# Preventing overlapping of div's

Tags: html, css

In the below(https://jsfiddle.net/9cc2xvbs/), how do I prevent overlapping of text, or wrap the text contents.

Style

```
div.relative {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
} 

div.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

Body:

```
<div class="relative"><p>This div element has position: relative;<p>
  <div class="absolute"><p>This div element has position: absolute;<p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want that smaller bod inside the larger one?

Comment: Yeah. The smaller div should be inside the larger one,

Comment: Just remove position: absolute; from your div.absolute

Comment: I would agree with @Blackcoat77 - and if you want it over to the right, just align it right.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that maybe you want to have a `div` inside a div with the green *inner* div over to the right and the *text* wrapping around?

```css
.relative {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
} 

.absolute2 {
    width: 190px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
.absolute1 {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="absolute1">
    <p>This is some text that should wrap around the second div as there are now two DIVs in the parent div</p>
  </div>
  <div class="absolute2">
    <p>This is some text that should wrap around the second div as there are now two DIVs in the parent div</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

div.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

.first{
  width:50%;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <p class="first">
    This div element has position: relative;
  <p>
  <div class="absolute">
    <p>This div element has position: absolute;
    <p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9cc2xvbs/ has been updated with your code, but the text does not wrap as width is set as 50%. How do I wrap the text to come below the absolute div box?

Answer (score 0):

The clasic answer would be to use a float. Is there any reason to use position: absolute ?

You will also need top change the order of the element and the innerHTML:

```css
div.relative {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
} 

div.absolute {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="absolute"><p>This div element is floated right<p></div>
  <p>This div element has position: relative;<p>
</div>
```